# How to search files of particular type in a tftp server using python?

Tags: python, tftp

I have `tftp` server where I have put some files. Now I need to get files of a particular type from the server.

This is what I currently do to get a file I know the name of

```
ip = '10.12.43.122'
def get_file():
    time = datetime.utcnow()
    filename = 'snapshot.' + ip + '.' +  str(time.day) + '-' + str(time.month) + '-' + str(time.year)
    print("filename", filename)
    cmd = 'tftp -v ' + TFTP_SERVER + ' -c get ' + filename
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    print("output", output)

get_file()
```

I get a message that the file is downloaded. But here I know what exactly the file is called.

What I want to do is to get the files that contains the `ip` mentioned. In the above, you can see I have defined an `ip` and it gets the particular file. Now I want to get all the files having that `ip` in their name. How do I do it?